# Set "compliance calculated date" on item title block in Oracle Agile PLM

Tags: java, oracle-agile-plm

If there are internal specifications in the Compliance tab of item, then by clicking "calculate compliance", following title block fields are populated:

- Compliance calculated date
- Overall compliance

But when only external specifications are present, these fields are not set. Following sdk method can Populate "overall compliance"

```
Item.setOverallCompliance()
```

But date field is not populated, is there any way this filed can be populated?

Comment: Are you trying to set the date using change order (by rolling revision) otherwise it's not possible.